# Override a CSS of a formatselect in TinyMCE dropdown with Vue.js

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, tinymce

I have integrated tinyMCE editor into my Vue.js Application.

```
:init="{
         height: 800,
         menubar: false,
          inline: true,
         setup: (editor) => {
           editor.on('change keyup undo', function(e) {
            updateValue(editor.getContent())
           })
         },
         plugins: [
           'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
           'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
           'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount textcolor'
         ],
         toolbar:  field.toolbar || 'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic forecolor | \
           alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | \
           bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help'
       }"
```

The issue is when I click in the options of the TinyMCE Editor say Paragaph the options are somehow overwritten and the headings are shown like in the picture.
[Here is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQWVY.png)

I tried adding some css but I don't know what the problem is. How can I fix it to show the Headings in the paragraph normally?

```
  .mce-content-body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 300px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #e2e8f0;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: white;
  }

  .tox-tinymce {
    @extend %formFieldBase;
  }
```